# How to show lightning layout item in 2 columns in LWC?

Tags: lightning-web-components, javascript, lightning-design-system

I created visual picker LWC component, the component is working as expected but unable to change the items to 2 columns instead of single column. I tried to use  size="6" class="slds-col slds-size_6-of-12" but nothing is working.
I want to show something like below.
[image]

LWC Component:

**html:**

```
<template>
    <lightning-card>

            <lightning-layout vertical-align="start" class="slds-grid slds-wrap">
                <lightning-layout-item size="6" class="slds-col slds-size_6-of-12" padding="around-small">
                    <!--<div class="slds-visual-picker slds-visual-picker_vertical">-->
                        <!--<lightning-card title="Multi select non coverable">-->
                            <template for:each={items2} for:item="item">
                                <div class="slds-visual-picker slds-visual-picker_vertical" key={item.idx}>
                                    <input type="checkbox" id={item.idx} value={item.label} name="set2" onchange={handleSet2Change} disabled={item.disabled} />
                                    <label for={item.idx}>
                                        <span class="slds-visual-picker__figure slds-visual-picker__text slds-align_absolute-center">
                                            <div class="slds-media slds-media_center slds-align_absolute-center slds-m-left_xx-small">
                                                <lightning-icon icon-name={item.icon} alternative-text="Account" title="Account"></lightning-icon>
                                                <lightning-icon variant="inverse" class="slds-icon_container slds-visual-picker__text-check" icon-name="utility:check" alternative-text="check" size="x-small" title="small size"></lightning-icon>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="slds-media__body slds-border_left slds-p-around_small">
                                                <h2 class="slds-truncate slds-text-heading_small" title={item.label}>{item.label}</h2>
                                                <!--<p class="slds-m-top_small">Harness your team&#x27;s collective know-how with our powerful knowledge base</p>-->
                                            </div>
                                        </span>
                                    </label>
                                </div>
                            </template>
                </lightning-layout-item>
            </lightning-layout>
    </lightning-card>
</template>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put lightning-layout-item inside the iteration. It will start coming as two column layout.

```
<lightning-card>
        <lightning-layout vertical-align="start" class="slds-grid slds-wrap">
                <template for:each={items2} for:item="item">
                    <lightning-layout-item key={item.idx} size="6" class="slds-col slds-size_6-of-12" padding="around-small">
                        <div class="slds-visual-picker slds-visual-picker_vertical" key={item.idx}>
                            <input type="checkbox" id={item.idx} value={item.label} name="set2" onchange={handleSet2Change} disabled={item.disabled} />
                            <label for={item.idx}>
                                <span class="slds-visual-picker__figure slds-visual-picker__text slds-align_absolute-center">
                                    <div class="slds-media slds-media_center slds-align_absolute-center slds-m-left_xx-small">
                                        <lightning-icon icon-name={item.icon} alternative-text="Account" title="Account"></lightning-icon>
                                        <lightning-icon variant="inverse" class="slds-icon_container slds-visual-picker__text-check" icon-name="utility:check" alternative-text="check" size="x-small" title="small size"></lightning-icon>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="slds-media__body slds-border_left slds-p-around_small">
                                        <h2 class="slds-truncate slds-text-heading_small" title={item.label}>{item.label}</h2>
                                        <!--<p class="slds-m-top_small">Harness your team&#x27;s collective know-how with our powerful knowledge base</p>-->
                                    </div>
                                </span>
                            </label>
                        </div>
                    </lightning-layout-item>
                </template>
        </lightning-layout>
    </lightning-card>
```

see the result from my org:-

[image]

Comment: Thanks it worked.